# SVG Arc Doesn't Go to Edge of Circle

Tags: svg

I am hand-crafting an SVG to show a circle with n segments, m of which are filled in.

In my first simple test case, I set n = 4 and m = 1. I draw a circle, then 4 paths to show the division between the 4 quadrants of the circle, and I have a path that fills in one of the quadrants with color using an arc command. However, the filled in portion of the arc does not completely reach the edge of the circle.

Here is my SVG:

```
<svg width="150" height="150" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M 75 10 A 75 75 0 0 1 140 75 L 75 75 Z" fill="green" stroke="none"/>
    <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="65" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M75,10 L75,75" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M140,75 L75,75" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M75,140 L75,75" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M10,75 L75,75" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg>
```

[image: SVG Circle with 4 segments]

I get the same problem when I render an SVG with n = 3. In fact, the gap is even more pronounced:

```
<svg width="150" height="150" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M 75 10 A 75 75 0 0 1 131.29165 107.5 L 75 75 Z" fill="green" stroke="none"/>
    <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="65" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M 75 10 L 75 75" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M 131.29165 107.5 L75,75" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M 18.70834 107.5 L75,75" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg>
```

[image]

I remember reading that arcs do have some limitations, particularly when it comes to an arc that represents a complete circle, since the exact path would be undefined. However, I didn't realize that this meant that longer and longer arcs became progressively more and more narrow relative to the circle they inscribe. Am I doing something wrong with my SVG? Why aren't my arcs perfectly filling the "wedge" of the circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have the radius set wrongly to 75 rather than 65:

```
<svg width="150" height="150" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M 75 10 A 65 65 0 0 1 140 75 L 75 75 Z" fill="green" stroke="none"/>
    <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="65" stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M75,10 L75,75" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M140,75 L75,75" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M75,140 L75,75" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path d="M10,75 L75,75" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: Whoops... That feels like an extremely ameture mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, we all make them :-) And sometimes we just can't see what's in front of us! Good luck with your project.